# Baffling trigger error: "An error was raised during trigger execution"

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a C# application (Windows Service) that runs an ALTER TABLE against a SQL Server 2016 table to alter/add some columns, for some reason it throws this error:

*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An error was raised during trigger execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if any, has been rolled back.*

Note that:

- the error only happens with the ALTER TABLE to add or alter columns, the CREATE TABLE  that creates the table works fine;
- the same TSQL that is failing runs successfully in SSMS connected to the database with the same credentials as the C# application;
- error happens with many tables in the same database, not just one;
- monitoring activity with SQL Profiles does not show any errors not triggers being executed;
- there are no triggers on the table nor on the database!

Any ideas? Could the message be a red herring and have nothing to do with trigger?

Here is the full error message with the TSQL statement:

```
System.Exception:
alter table [dbo].[MyTable] alter column [Date] datetime null;
alter table [dbo].[MyTable] add [TEST3] nvarchar(255) null;
alter table [dbo].[MyTable] alter column [Modified] datetime null;
alter table [dbo].[MyTable] alter column [Created] datetime null;
 ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An error was raised during trigger execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if any, has been rolled back.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Clearly you have a DDL trigger. Please show the code for it. It may be under Database Triggers, or under Server Triggers in SSMS. Perhaps the service is connecting to a different machine, instance or database.

Comment: Another question is why are you altering tables? It's not really a normal case of work to do that, unless you're working with dynamic stuff

Comment: The error you provided seems to be unrelated to altering tables: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2094881-sql-error-0x80131904

Comment: @nicomp That HRESULT number is just the generic one for any `SqlException`

Comment: @siggemannen, that's the case, I do dynamic stuff

Comment: @nicomp, it's definitely not firewall related, the application connects successfully to the db

Comment: @Charlieface I also thought the error code is a generic one, and I agree there must be triggers somewhere, I just can't find them (asked the customer to check for server ones...)

Comment: @Charlieface that was it, a server trigger! It does not show running a "select * from sys.server_triggers;" in the database itself but it does show when run in MASTER, and in SSMS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a server trigger!

For some reason (that I have to investigate), the trigger does not show running a "select * from sys.server_triggers;" from the database itself but it does show when run from MASTER, and it does show in SSMS.